# Use simple-line-icons symbol as placeholder

Tags: html, css, fonts, placeholder

I've included [simple line icons](http://simplelineicons.com/) font in my project and I would like to add a symbol from this font as a form input placeholder. Here's what I've done so far:

1. included `simple-line-icons.css` in document head: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="simple-line-icons.css" media="all" type="text/css" />`
2. point to font source files in `simple-line-icons.css` (`woff`, `woff2`, `ttf`, `svg`)
3. define a `.input` class (for inputs where I want to add symbols) containing the icons font family  `.input { font-family:'simple-line-icons', inherit;}`
4. find in `simple-line-icons.css` the unicode of the symbol I want to add: `.icon-user:before { content: "\e005"; }`
5. define a placeholder containing the unicode of the symbol: `<input class="input" type="text" placeholder="&#xe047;Your name" />`

Unfortunately, the symbol is not displayed correctly.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try put the icon outside the input field. something like this:

```
<style>
.input{
    padding-left:20px;}
.icon-user{
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
}
.input-wrapper{
    position:relative;
}
</style>
<div class='input-wrapper'>
<div class='icon-user'></div>
<input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Your name" />
<div>
```

Comment: Yes, I've already thought about that (and probably I'll do it, if placeholder solution is not feasible). Thanks for the suggestion.